# Can not Implicitly Convert SymmetrySecurityKey Type

Tags: c#, token

Plz any one help me i can't find the problem!!!
[Can not Implicitly Convert SymmetrySecurityKey Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGQIF.png)

```
  var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value);
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(x => x.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddScoped<IAuthRepository, AuthRepository>();
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKeys = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
        }
```

Comment: Please just post your code in the question and describe your issue. This question, as is, won't get you anywhere here.

Comment: @Sudsy1002 that's french. Also this site is in english and that's a "pro" place, so "plz help me!!!!" is clearly not appropriate, aswell as begging, and the least you could do is traducing your error in english as it's clearly not our job to search wich langage you speak and traduct from there.

Comment: `IssuerSigningKeys = new[] { new SymmetricSecurityKey(key) },`

Comment: Thank you Ron :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is essentially "Cannot convert from SymmetricSecurityKey(string) to IEnumerable<SymmetricSecurityKey>". This means that the `IssuerSigningKeys` is expecting an `IEnumerable` (`List` or `Array`) of `SymmetricSecurityKey` instead of a single value.

The fix is easy, give it an array:

```
services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKeys = new[] { new SymmetricSecurityKey(key) },
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false
                    };
                });
```